# Fixed display name in the profile page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, profile-page, display-names

Currently the display name (`user-card-name`) and the title (`current-position`) in the profile page is in a `<div>` (`about`), which also contains the league rank (`top-badge`) and the about me (`bio`).

The whole `<div>` is scrollable so when scrolled the name and the title disappear.

[image]

---

I suggest that the name and the title should stay `fixed` and only the about me (`bio`) section should be scrollable.

[image]

---

Because it looks a bit more professional when the display name is always there, and usually the about me (`bio`) part is the one with a long text which needs scrolling.

Comment: For me it looks a bit bothering to always have the name and the subtitle always visible.